# Lazy Loading A Module Route As A Child Of A Component

Tags: angular

**Problem**

I have two components that are the parents of all other routes. But I need to add lazy loading to my application. So I am trying to figure out how to lazy load the modules as children of a parent component which has the sole purpose of acting as a template.

**Example**

I have `app.routing.ts` which holds two routes.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: '', component: PublicComponent, data: { title: 'Public Views' }, children: PUBLIC_ROUTES },
    { path: '', component: SecureComponent, canActivate: [Guard], data: { title: 'Secure Views' }, children: SECURE_ROUTES }
];
```

This allows me to control any secure routes through one template and any public routes through a different template. Those templates are `PublicComponent` and `SecureComponent`.

So if we follow the path of `PublicComponent` I would create the `PUBLIC_ROUTES` and lazyload each component that is public through that route path.

```
public.routes.ts

export const PUBLIC_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
   { path: 'about', loadChildren: 'app/public/about/about.module#AboutModule' }
];
```

As you can see above I am loading HomeComponent so that it will be the default page to load in the application but I want to lazy load the `AboutModule` as a child of the PublicComponent.

**Explanation**

I assume I could write some fancy `*ngIf` statements to make this work for myself but it would be ideal to find out how to do this. Right now it loads the `HomeComponent` as it should but when I go to the `AboutModule` it shows the templates but leaves out all the `AboutModule html`.

**Question**

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so where I can find an example? I have not been able to make this work.

Comment: It shows an error on the console? Or in the webpack build process?

Comment: Nope! There is no error. It just is literally not loading the html from the about page in the templates. but the correct header and footer show up. I am beginning to wonder if this is just not possible. I am looking for some confirmation so I can just resort to *ngIf. Also if you do not think this question has an answer please up vote for the sake that maybe we can get one. I know multiple people have been trying to figure this out.

Comment: Did you add another `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your PublicComponent ?

Comment: There is one in there yes.